# Mod_Rewrite Apache ProxyPass?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

I have two websites; OLDSITE and NEWSITE. The OLDSITE has 120 IP Address that it has with it, and the NEWSITE had 5. I want to be able to separate everything from OLDSITE and NEWSITE so they are not tied together but use them on the same linux computer. My current apache setup is this:

```
Listen 80
NameVirtualHost *



<VirtualHost *>
        ServerName oldsite.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@oldsite.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>


        RewriteEngine   on
        RewriteCond     %{HTTP_HOST}                       ^([^.]+)\.oldsite\.com$
        RewriteCond     /home/%1/                          -d
        RewriteRule     ^(.+)                              %{HTTP_HOST}$1
        RewriteRule     ^([^.]+)\.oldsite\.com/media/(.*)  /home/$1/dir/media/$2
        RewriteRule     ^([^.]+)\.oldsite\.com/(.*)        /home/$1/www/$2
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost newsite.com>
        ServerName newsite.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@newsite.com
        DocumentRoot /var/newsite/
        <Directory /var/newsite/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>


        RewriteEngine   on
        RewriteCond     %{HTTP_HOST}                        ^([^.]+)\.newsite\.com$
        RewriteCond     /home/%1/                           -d
        RewriteRule     ^(.+)                               %{HTTP_HOST}$1
        RewriteRule     ^([^.]+)\.newsite\.com/media/(.*)   /home/$1/dir/media/$2
        RewriteRule     ^([^.]+)\.newsite\.com/(.*)         /home/$1/www/$2

</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *>
        ServerName panel.oldsite.com
        ProxyPass / http://panel.oldsite.com:10000/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://panel.oldsite.com:10000/

        <Proxy *>
          allow from all
        </Proxy>

</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *>
        ServerName panel.newsite.com
        ProxyPass / http://panel.newsite.com:10000/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://panel.newsite.com:10000/

        <Proxy *>
            allow from all
        </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

I want to be able to access anything that is newsite.com and have it go to the /var/newsite unless their is a home directory...and then if its panel.newsite.com I want it to automatically do a proxypass to panel.newsite.com:10000...   With this setup, it works perfect for oldsite.com.... both the proxy and the webpages... However, having the Virtualhost set to newsite.com renders the proxypass worthless. If I change the Virtualhost for the newsite.com to a wildcard, the proxypass will work but anything thats a subdomain of newsite.com won't work. so newsite.com will work, but www.newsite.com will not load correctly.

I am assuming that when everything is wildcarded, then the ServerName somewhat acts like a RewriteCond and actually just applies the stuff to that URL. It uses the Virtualhost * (oldsite.com) and lets  ANYTHING.oldsite.com work, but the second virtualhost * (newsite.com) only newsite.com will work... www.newsite.com will not.  If I change the order of them, the opposite is true. So apparently it doesn't like me using 2 wildcards...

I tried just making the Servername *.newsite.com .......but that would be too easy. I am not sure what I can do to do what I want? Perhaps I should make the ProxyPass included in the VirtualHosts and use something like:

```
RewriteCond     %{HTTP_HOST}            ^panel\.newsite\.com$   [NC]
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$                  http://panel.newsite.com:10000/ [P] 
ProxyPassReverse /                      http://panel.newsite.com:10000/
```

but that doesnt seem to want to login to webmin, it loads the login page but isnt working how the ProxyPass & ProxyPassReverse does.

Answer (score 1):

If Apache can't find a VirtualHost with a matching ServerName or ServerAlias, it uses the first VirtualHost found in the config file as a default. With the configuration above, I think that for example "www.newsite.com" would end up being handled by the oldsite.com VirtualHost.

Have you tried adding a ServerAlias line to each of the two main VirtualHosts - i.e.

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName oldsite.com
    ServerAlias *.oldsite.com
    ...
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName newsite.com
    ServerAlias *.newsite.com
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```